# Verify if the function $f(x,y)$ is differentiable in $(x,y) = (0,0)$ and $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Verify if the function $f(x,y)$ is differentiable in $(x,y) = (0,0)$ and $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$

$$f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
  2xy (\frac{x^2 - y^2}{x^+ y^2}) & x^2 + y^2 \ne 0 \\[4pt]
 0 & other case\\
 \end{cases}
$$

This is my work i found partial derivatives but i stuck in how can i choose if the function is differentiable or not? please some help.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have avoided much of your calculation, by remarking that the sum product and quotient of differentiable functions is differentiable. This solves your question for $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$. Your work for $(0,0)$ seems right to me.

Comment: but in (x,y) = (0,0) i stuck i compute the derivative in that point and find the second derivative then? i don't know what can i conclude...

Comment: You get the derivatives in the two directions, the limits exist, so it is differentiable. Why calculate the second derivative ?

Comment: @Knight Verifying that the partial derivatives exist is not enough to conclude differentiability. The latter is a stronger requirement and you have, in fact, not shown that the function is differentiable. Computing the second derivatives is irrelevant and does not help.